# How to make OnGUI window block mouse clicks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have seen a lot of suggestions on this, but nothing seems to be working for me.

I have a window made in OnGUI that is displayed over game's Canvas. I need to somehow prevent the canvas from getting mouse clicks when the mouse is over my window.

I can only make changes to the Canvas and input handling during runtime.

Comment: Do not use OnGUI with Canvas. In fact, do not use OnGUI. You should be using the UI system. That's it. OnGUI is not required

Comment: What's the purpose of your OnGUI elements? Is it specifically to block input? Just curious why you're using both the new UI and OnGUI calls vs all new UI.

Comment: Do not use OnGUI, just forget about it! Use Unity UI system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to disable GraphicRaycaster on the game's Canvas object.